# Which free and easy-to-use RSS writers are there for Windows?

Tags: windows, rss

Are there any free and easy-to-use RSS writers for Windows? I'm hoping to find something that can save my time writing raw XML files; I only need the very basic functions of RSS.

Comment: Pro tip: sometimes searching for a faster way to do something takes up enough time to say that finding a faster way is not worth it.

Comment: Does it have to be RSS? Atom is simpler.

Comment: @grawity, better support both, any recommendations?

Comment: @digitxp, any recommendations? I searched Google for an hour, not can not find a free one.

Comment: @George2 Why both? Both RSS2 and Atom are supported equally in all readers known to me. (I don't know any existing writer, however.)

Comment: @George2 Couple a [tutorial](http://www.astaara.com/rss-feed-code.html) I found on Google, and then use your favorite text editor to create the RSS file from that. Save it as blahblah.rss or blahblah.xml, whichever suits your taste.

Comment: But what exactly do you mean by RSS writer? Do you want a feed for your blog or something?

Comment: I prefer to use RSS format, any recommended writers?

Comment: @digitxp, I have found a library to generate RSS for developer. I am currently looking for some GUI tools to generate RSS manually for non-developer (e.g. manually write literal title, author, description, link without XML knowledge, and then using generate XML function to generate raw XML for RSS).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this [web form](http://www.rssfeedssubmit.com/rss-generator/).

Or this [software](http://www.alentum.com/rsseditor/).

Comment: The 2nd software you recommended -- RSS Editor is not free?

Comment: Nope. RSS writers are one of those extremely useless functions, so useless that shareware authors have a monopoly on it and charge an insane amount of money. Without knowing what you want to use it for, that form is about as close as you'll get to a solution.